# How can we write test class for getting all record types of case Object in salesforce

Tags: apex

Here is a **Apex Class** that is getting all record types and return list at end

```
public static List<RecordType> fetchRecordTypeValues(){
        string query = 'SELECT Id,Name FROM RecordType WHERE IsActive=TRUE AND SobjectType =\''+'Case'+'\'';
            List<RecordType> rtNames = new List<RecordType>();
            Schema.SObjectType objType = Case.SObjectType;
            for(RecordTypeInfo rt : objType.getDescribe().getRecordTypeInfos()){
                if(rt.isAvailable() && rt.Name != 'Master')
                {
                  rtNames.add(new RecordType(Id = rt.getRecordTypeId(), Name = rt.getName()));   
                }

             } 
        return rtNames;

    }
```

**Test Class**

```
    public static void fetchRecordTypeValuesTest(){
            RecordType rt = new RecordType(Name = 'OA');
            RecordType rt1 = new RecordType(Name = 'OM');
            List<RecordType> lrt = new List<RecordType>([SELECT Id, Name FROM RecordType WHERE SObjectType = 'Case' AND IsActive = TRUE LIMIT 1]);
            lrt.add(rt);
            lrt.add(rt1);
            Test.startTest();
            upsert lrt;
            Test.stopTest();

            list<RecordType> obj1 = new CaseAuraServiceLWCC().fetchRecordTypeValues();
            system.assertequals(obj1.size(),2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't insert Record Types. They are setup objects.

Your unit test class should test this code as you would any other code, save that you are going to rely on the actual Record Types present in your org. Call the functionality, and then write assertions against the results to validate its behavior.

As an aside, returning `RecordType` sObjects doesn't make a lot of sense to me. It's more typical to cache specific facets of the Record Types that are of interest, or of course the `RecordTypeInfo` itself. You also have a dead-code query string in your class.

Answer (score 0):

Since you just want the Name and the Id, You can write code that gets your RecordTypes without burning a query.

rom Summer'18 https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_apex_developer_name.htm

Get the Developer Name for Record Types More Easily
We added Apex methods to help you get the developer name for record types more easily. Previously, the developer name was accessible only via SOQL on the RecordType SObject, and not via describe information.

Where: This change applies to Lightning Experience and Salesforce Classic in Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Developer editions.

You can use the following methods to get the developer name.

`Schema.DescribeSObjectResult.getRecordTypeInfosByDeveloperName()`
`Schema.RecordTypeInfo.getDeveloperName()`

`Id objectRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Case').getRecordTypeId();`

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_apex_developer_name.htm